# React-router not rendering Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

This is a sample code I'm trying to implement. But I can't find the reason why react is not rendering the component. I am including react-router from CDN. Please Help

```
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
 var HomePage  = React.createClass({
      render:function(){
        return(
          <div>
            <h1>Hi World</h1>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
  </Router>
  ,document.getElementById('mydiv')

);
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  are you browsing `http://<domain>/home`?

Comment: There's an error on the console for a split second.GET localhost:8080/home 404 not found. But after that there's no error.

Comment: Try installing and `import` react-router, instead of using CDN.

Comment: Getting the same error after installing and importing. I have edited the import statement in code above

Comment: getting the error "require is not defined" now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try to use hashHistory**, [jsbin example with CDN](http://jsbin.com/hamipopisu/1/edit?html,js,output).

[Example with imports](http://www.webpackbin.com/EJppJfDLZ)

**browserHistory** requires [additional configuration](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v2.0.0-rc5/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server) on the server side to serve up URLs.

```
var ReactRouter = window.ReactRouter;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory; 


 var HomePage  = React.createClass({
      render:function(){
        return(
          <div>
            <h1>Hi World</h1>
           </div>
        );
      }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
  </Router>
  ,document.getElementById('mydiv')

);
```

Comment: can you provide jsbin/ jsfiddle

Comment: check out my examples, with CDN and with imports

Comment: for jsbin you also need "/", since you don't have acess to path bar, see my examples

Comment: click to on link ```go to "/home"```  to check, that it works

Comment: on my local computer. I dont have a route to '/' but when i put '/home' on address bar then the route doesnt work.

Comment: are you using hashHistory?

Comment: Yes. and what is the error in this http://jsbin.com/legakow/edit?html,js,output ?

Comment: Is the because I am not providing '/' route ? But in the react-router documentation I have seen examples which dont contain '/' routes.

Comment: as i wrote above you need '/' for jsbin for testing purpose.

Comment: it only needs for jsbin

Comment: because jsbin tries to open '/' on start script

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zozofe/1/edit?html,js,output I copy pasted the code to js bin and its working , but the exact same code is not working on my local system. I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Why the anchor tag in the html is not showing up on jsbin ?

Comment: [example without '/' ](http://jsbin.com/xamakujoto/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: try "#/home" path in address bar

Comment: Working !!! Thanks. I dont know what wrong was happening. I just restarted the server serving the files. Though I got the warning in the console  "ReactRouter.js:370 Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes"

Comment: But I am getting routes like this "http://localhost:8080/#/home?_k=wd0216"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116667/discussion-between-maroof-and-utro).